# Classes isn't works (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have script with AJAX request like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    question_block();
});

function question_block() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("QuestionBlocks", "Interwier")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function(result) {
            var email = result;
            for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
                var question = '<div class="activeQue" style="font-size:20px;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">' + email[i].Question1 + '</div>'+
                    '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;" >' + email[i].Question2 + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;" >' + email[i].Question3 + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;" >' + email[i].Question4 + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;" >' + email[i].Question5 + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;" >' + email[i].Question6 + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;" >' + email[i].Question7 + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;" >' + email[i].Question8 + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;" >' + email[i].Question9 + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="hiddenQue" style="font-size:20px;" >' + email[i].Question10 + '</div>';
                $("#questions").append(question);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Smth wrong in controller");
        }
    });
}

var myLink = document.getElementById('next');
myLink.onclick = function functionName(){
    var element = $(".activeQue");
    $(element).removeClass("activeQue").addClass("hiddenQue");
    $(element).next().removeClass("hiddenQue").addClass("activeQue");
}
</script>
```

In css I have this class

```
.hiddenQue {
   display: none;
}
```

But when I make AJAX request I see my divs with classes, but `hiddenQue` property not `display:none`

I don't understand why.

How I can fix this?

Comment: $(".activeQue") is already a jQuery object, you don't need to use $(...) again, juste use element.removeClass("activeQue").addClass("hiddenQue") and so on.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces this problem

Comment: Are you sure you included CSS file?

Comment: Yes, I sure about it.@Hulothe

Comment: Can you see css reference on firebug or inspect element etc.

Comment: I add class in `site.css file.

And I have this in inspect element `<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet">`

So I have  css file included in View @himyata

Comment: I've tested your code and see no reason for this not to work. Either you haven't referenced your CSS properly, or there is something else in your style sheet that's negating the `display: none;`.

Comment: put **.hiddenQue  {display: none !important};**

Comment: It  works, thank's@MajidParvin